# Kubuntu - GUI context menu sudo/root

Tags: sudo, root, nautilus, kubuntu

A couple of years ago I found something in a package manager that added a context menu item that allowed me to open files and save them normally without being harassed about file permissions. Can anyone remind me what the name of it was please?

Comment: Is it in Kubuntu or Ubuntu? The title suggest that, It is in Kubuntu but your tag is [tag:ubuntu]

Comment: Gilles decided to edit my post and changed it. >__> It is Kubuntu so I can test KHTML/Konqueror.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted this because people cannot judge the answer given to this question without this crucial information

Comment: I agree, I have to CONSTANTLY tell people not to edit my posts, this happens to about HALF my posted questions.

Comment: You can discuss this matter at chat with moderator or meta.

Answer (score 2):

Came across it in a search: `nautilus-gksu`.

Comment: `nautilus-gksu` will never work on kubuntu

Comment: Correct, unfortunately that was while I was trying a distro with GNOME, that will hopefully help GNOME users at least.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `gksudo` from the [gksu](http://www.nongnu.org/gksu/) package.

Comment: Trying your suggestion...

Comment: Installed and restarted, not appearing in the context menu for /etc/fstab in Dolphin. Not sure what to do now...

Comment: If you could please follow this up when you have a chance and I get this working I'd be more than happy to accept the answer.

Comment: As far as I know, `gksu` is made for gnome based Ubuntu, It will not work with Kubuntu